# What is the difference between arithmetic and geometrical series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the difference between arithmetic and geometrical series?
Also what are they?
How do they look like?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean by "how do they look like?" but if you were to plot a geometric sequence you'd see an *exponential growth* whereas an arithmetic sequence has a *linear growth*.  In both cases, the sequence of partial sums would of course grow *even faster*.

Answer (score 4):

Geometric and arithmetic are two names that are given to different sequences that follow a rather strict pattern for how one term follows from the one before.

An arithmetic sequence is characterised by the fact that every term is equal to the term before plus some fixed constant, called the *difference* of the sequence. For instance,
$$
1,4,7,10,13,\ldots
$$
is an arithmetic sequence with difference $3$, while
$$
1,2,4,6,7,10,\ldots
$$
is not an arithmetic sequence.

A geometric sequence follows a very similar idea, except instead of *adding* a fixed number to get from one term to the next, you *multiply* by a number, called the *quotient* of the sequence. For instance,
$$
1,2,4,8,16,32,\ldots
$$
is a geometric sequence with quotient $2$, while
$$
3,6,13,23,48,\ldots
$$
fails to be a geometric sequence.

The word "series" is usually used to signify a sum of consecutive terms in a sequence. In the case of arithmetic series the sum is almost always of a finite number of terms. (A commonly mentioned exception is $1+2+3+4+\cdots =-\frac{1}{12}$, which while apparently just nonsense, has been verified experimentally in quantum mechanics. Specifically in the context of the Casimir effect.)

In a geometric series, if the quotient is between $-1$ and $1$, one can take the sum of all the infinitely many terms of the sequence. A notable example one should be familiar with is
$$
\frac12 + \frac14+\frac18+\cdots =1
$$

Comment: I just deleted my answer because I was not sure about the word 'series' in the english language: Isn't a *series* generally a sequence of partial sums of a *sequence*, or can 'series' also be used in place of 'sequence'?

Comment: @flawr You might be right. I'll edit the answer.